# Location of tld file in web app?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, taglib

I found tld file is lying under location /webapp/WEB-INF/tld in my project. As per my understanding
tld file should lie directly under WEB-INF. I am not getting how come how tag libraries are resolved from
WEB-INF/tld instead of WEB-INF ?

Hereis the inclusion of tag lib in my jsp

```
 <%@ taglib uri="com.myComp.utils.customFunctions" prefix="custfunc"%>
```

For info i am using Spring MVC. I am not sure if it is doing some magic here.

Comment: The documentation is a bit vague, but I do believe it states that it must be in the WEB-INF or a subdirectory of the WEB-INF. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html

Comment: ... or you have the tld's on the classpath multiple times, like in a jar. You could try temporarily removing that tld folder and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

put tld file in "WEB-INF" folder access using uri start with **"WEB-INF/demo.tld"**